# Trying to place the name in the text of a file

Tags: shell-script, filenames, here-document

I am trying to put the name of the file I just made in my script into the text of the file, but I can't seem to find how to let it print out the `$name` in the file. Can someoene help me?

```
cat <<'EOF' >>$name
This file is named $name
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not quote the string `EOF`. Do it like this:

```
cat <<_EOT_ >>$name
This file is named $name
_EOT_
```

If the delimiter is quoted no expansions are performed in the here-document:

> If any part of word (EOT) is quoted, ... , and the lines in the here-
>          document are not expanded.

Comment: so i am trying to compile a .java file in my vim script but it keeps giving the error "could not find or load main class name.java" while i have put a main class in my .java file, can u help with that?

Comment: @floriandewulf That is a java question, please open a new question, thanks.